# how do you useCallback and useMemo following api calls?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm building my application and at some point it needs to get data from an api. I want to optimize my lifecycle behaviours but I can't use either `useCallback` or `useMemo` without the conditional rendering rules of hook warning/error. The code example below shows the issue, but essentially, if data doesn't load (null) I need to show a loading or error message. In doing so, the logic following that catch is all conditional and thus creates lifecycle issues. Any thoughts on how to better handle this?

```
const TranscriptController = (mode: 'single' | 'multi') => {
  const { setPlay } = useContext(VideoPlayerContext) as IVideoPlayerContext;
  const {
    transcript,
    translation,
    currSelectionIdx,
    setTranscript,
    setTranslation,
    handlePlayNext,
    handlePlayPrevious
  } = useContext(TranscriptContext) as ITranscriptContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    setTranscript(MOCK_TRANSCRIPT_DE);
    setTranslation(MOCK_TRANSLATE_EN);
  }, [setTranscript, setTranslation]);

// * data doesnt load, show this message
  if (!transcript || !translation) {
    return <Typography>Resources not found</Typography>;
  }

// * otherwise ...

  // * cannot use callback/memo hooks here or in downstream components
  const renderOnlyActiveSelection = () =>
    ActiveSelection(
      transcript.selections[currSelectionIdx],
      translation.selections[currSelectionIdx],
      `active-selection`,
      true
    );

  const renderMultipleSelections = transcript.selections.map((selection, i) => {
    if (i === currSelectionIdx) {
      return ActiveSelection(
        transcript.selections[currSelectionIdx],
        translation.selections[currSelectionIdx],
        `selection_${i}`
      );
    } else {
      return InActiveSelection(selection, translation.selections[i], i);
    }
  });

  // * output
  return mode === 'single'
    ? renderOnlyActiveSelection()
    : renderMultipleSelections;
};

export default TranscriptController;
```

Comment: You have to always use hooks before any `return` statement. So, place your `useMemo` and `useCallback` before your conditional return.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook to fetch your data and set a loading state.  Below is a quick example although it's missing error handling.

```
export function useFetchData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  // Could create error state and return it from the hook as well

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('someEndpoint')
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  return [isLoading, data]
}
```

Then call the hook at the top of your component and conditionally render some jsx if `isLoading` is true.

```
const [isLoading, data] = useFetchData()

if (isLoading) {
    return <>Loading...</>
}
```